# How to go 'forward' in react navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

When using react-navigation when you go from one screen to another screen you can easily swipe back to get to the previous screen, but it does not allow you to swipe forward to get back to the screen you came from. Is this possible?

In other words

Screen 1 -> Screen 2 -> Screen 3

Go to Screen 1, then to Screen 2, then to Screen 3. Then you swipe back and get to Screen 2, and swipe back again to get to Screen 1. But if you go from Screen 1 to Screen 2 to Screen 3, then swipe back to Screen 2, how do you swipe forward in Screen 2 to get back to Screen 3? Is this not a thing?

I have researched how to do this and can't find it in the docs anywhere. Please let me know if I am missing it somewhere. Thanks!

**EDIT**: What I am looking for is the equivalent of [backBehavior](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-top-tab-navigator.html#tabnavigatorconfig) in the docs but for forwardBehavior

Comment: Hi Ronald, I'm after achieving precisely the same thing. I want to bind it to the default response for the screen to make entering data as convenient as possible. I tried hidden top tabs, but that looks

Comment: This is my problem too. I created a self push screen which every time push a new same screen to stack, but i can't find how i can go forward between generated screens without headache.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to store forward route in each screen state and then go forward,but this will only help to go one page forward.

to go multiple page forward you have to store it in asyncStorage or somewhere

Comment: Hi Vinil, Wading through the React Navigation docs as the moment .... wondering if you might have a pointer (or two) to examples of how this might be done. Cheers